# GeoServer version missing

Tags: geoserver

I have installed GeoServer 2.21.0 from the Web Archive geoserver.war
The problem is that when I login the version shows this:

```
@Project.Version@
```

instead of the version itself.
Here is a screenshot of what it shows:
[image: GeoServer version missing]

I searched on the web about how to handle it but with no luck.
Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Is everything else on the webserver working? If not, the server may not be connecting to the geoserver

Comment: I just figure out that when I try to submit something it gives me a bad request 400.

Comment: That looks like a locally compiled version

Comment: Does the webserver know how to connect to the geoserver? Look at the error logs for both.

Comment: @IanTurton I don't know what you mean exactly by locally compiled. I just deployed geoserver.war from the manager console of tomcat. On the other hand, when I open geoserver from it's default url (http://localhost:8080/geoserver), it looks like all works fine, but when I open tomcat from the virtualhost of Apache (https://mytomcat/geoserver) it opens it but with the above problems.

Answer (score 1):

My install of GeoServer 2.21.0 (from the [war](https://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.21.0/geoserver-2.21.0-war.zip)) shows the version correctly:

[image]

Which suggests that the war file you are running is not the correct one. I would expect to see that "version" if I was running GeoServer in eclipse built from local files for testing.

I would start the install again making sure to get a download from the [GeoServer site](https://geoserver.org).

Comment: The war file has been downloaded from the official website (https://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.21.0/geoserver-2.21.0-war.zip), so it is the correct one. On my last comment on the first post, I describe how it behaves when I change from the default url to url I created with virtualhost from Apache. The examples Tomcat has work properly on both cases, that's why I wonder why geoserver behaves differently and how can I handle it.

Comment: then apache is accessing a different tomcat or a different geoserver as that would make no difference to the GeoServer runtime

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72965157/tomcat-in-virtualhost-of-wamp-server-https) is the configuration I am using on the virtualhost. There is only one instance of Tomcat installed on the maschine and only one geoserver deployed. So from where does it read the different tomcat and geoserver, you suggest?

Comment: I have no idea, but adding a web server to the mix can not cause the issue you are reporting